# iPaper like module recommendation

Tags: 7

I am looking for a module that will enable me to upload and preview pdf files, word docs etc on the site. Something along the lines of http://drupal.org/files/images/screenshot_2.jpg. I would like it to be indexable and searchable on the site.

Any recommendations for the module that will allow me to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Embedded Google Docs Viewer](http://drupal.org/project/gdoc_field) and check whether your requirements are fulfilled or not. [Here](http://testbed7.m-so.com/content/simple-page-using-embedded-google-docs-viewer-file-formatter) is the demo of the module.

The Embedded Google Docs Viewer module adds a new formatter to the File field using the Field API. This formatter displays PDFs, Microsft Word documents, Powerpoint presentations, or Excel spreadsheets directly within a Drupal node.

Comment: Thank you @mohit_rocks

I take it one needs to have a google account and be logged in in order for this to work, is that correct?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working :(
I guess because I am uploading the files from my machine? 

I found this "Sorry, but as the module docs point out, the documents must be publicly accessible - Google can't format and display them if they can't be gotten to. So it won't work if you are using private file storage, are behind a firewall, or on a local site that is accessed with a "localhost" address."

@mohit_rocks

Comment: Let me install and check it..

Comment: I have tested it. It works perfectly. I have added **Upload Destination**  as public files while creating the fields. Try it out and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for that @mohit_rocks

For my content type the Upload destination is also se to Public files (
Select where the final files should be stored. Private file storage has significantly more overhead than public files, but allows restricted access to files within this field.)

I wonder why it's not working for me :(

Comment: Did you leave the File directory text field bank?

Comment: Yes.. i have kept it blank..You can test also on www.simplytest.me. On this site write the name of the project and launch sandbox and test it.. Check here: http://sca8f1901ce919e3.s3.simplytest.me/ username:admin password:admin This link will work for 30 minutes only..

Comment: Doh! Didn't get in on time :(

Comment: Create a new one at your own :) at http://simplytest.me/

Comment: Thanks @mohit_rocks

I keep getting the "The selected project shortname testonly could not be found." error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8473/discussion-between-mohit-rocks-and-kine456)

Comment: Thank you! @mohit_rocks
It works for pdf but not doc

http://sc539a4e8ca36ab5.s3.simplytest.me/node/1

Comment: Doc also works check it out here : http://sc539a4e8ca36ab5.s3.simplytest.me/node/2

Comment: How did you get it to work @mohit_rocks
I wonder why it didn't work for me? :S